# How to get SoapFault from external webservice?

Tags: webservices

I am invoking external webservice from Salesforce. For some cases if the response is not available the external system will send status message as SOAP default in the Response Header.

```
<ns0:SOAPFault xmlns:ns0="http://www.abc.com/schemas/Technical/CommonV2.0">
    <ns0:Fault>
        <ns0:ErrorCode>003</ns0:ErrorCode>
        <ns0:ErrorMsg>Material xxxx-yyyy does not exist.</ns0:ErrorMsg>
        <ns0:ErrorType>Business Error</ns0:ErrorType>
    </ns0:Fault>
<ns0:SOAPFault>
```

May I know how to process this SoapFault in salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now salesforce does not return the Soap Fault element or truncates it or something. I do not recall exactly but here is a post with a similar question with all the info you need

[Accessing the entire fault response from a CalloutException](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29384/accessing-the-entire-fault-response-from-a-calloutexception)